# I am using launch4j for the first time and I get following error

Tags: java, exception, runtime.exec, launch4j

I am using launch4j for the first time and I get following error

here is error log:

```
Compiling resources
C:\Program Files (x86)\Launch4j\bin\windres.exe: can't popen `type  C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\launch4j5018895285025730359rc': No error
Generated resource file...

LANGUAGE 0, 1
2 RCDATA BEGIN "1.0.0\0" END
18 RCDATA BEGIN "1\0" END
30 RCDATA BEGIN "2\0" END
21 RCDATA BEGIN "http://java.com/download\0" END
8 RCDATA BEGIN ".\0" END
20 RCDATA BEGIN "32\0" END
101 RCDATA BEGIN "An error occurred while starting the application.\0" END
102 RCDATA BEGIN "This application was configured to use a bundled Java Runtime Environment but the runtime is missing or corrupted.\0" END
103 RCDATA BEGIN "This application requires a Java Runtime Environment\0" END
104 RCDATA BEGIN "The registry refers to a nonexistent Java Runtime Environment installation or the runtime is corrupted.\0" END
17 RCDATA BEGIN "true\0" END

net.sf.launch4j.ExecException: Exec failed (1): C:\Program Files (x86)\Launch4j\bin\windres.exe --preprocessor=type -J rc -O coff -F pe-i386 C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\launch4j5018895285025730359rc C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\launch4j182279593561858687o
```

Comment: please help me for resolved this problem

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with your Launch4J XML file. I had a similar problem because I used an BMP and changed the extension to ICO but it wasn't a actual icon. All of your declared resources are check when you run your build.

In your case, it is telling you that `C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\launch4j5018895285025730359rc` doesn't exist. Check your Launch4J entries and make sure you are referencing valid files. Then try your build again.